# "swiperight" and "swipteleft" events for webpages with clickable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am going  to have  "swiperight" and "swipteleft" events in a webpage which will navigate the pages. The problem is that the pages have content which are clickable (tapable). How can I catch the swipe events on the page? I think I need an overlay on top of the page which captures the swipe events. But then how should I tap on the page content if I have an overlay?

Comment: But those are completely different events, you shouldn't have trouble differentiating between them. What have you written so far?

Comment: right, but the problem is that I can not catch the touch event after the page is filled with content. should I have something like $(document).on("swipeleft"... ? Actually this also didn't work. So I decided to have some overlay with large z-index to capture swipes

Comment: Oh I see, and with that approach you are not able to let the inputs "through" to lower levels, where you need taps. Can you remove the overlay and put the listener on body?

Comment: yes exactly. Thank you, it actually works when in the body.

Comment: Awesome, glad you fixed it. You're welcome! I've decided to write it as an answer in case someone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the overlay approach is that you are not able to let the input events "through" to the lower levels, where you need to listen for taps.

One solution is to remove the overlay and put the listener on the document body element (I believe the html element should work as well).

If things get way too complicated and you're forced to keep the overlay, you can delegate all the non-swipe events to the layer below the overlay.

Comment: How do you send only non-swipe events to the layer below and keep the swipe for overlay?

Comment: You'd have to intercept all events on the overlay, and if they are not swipes, send them to a layer under it you have already defined... It's a bit more complicated, I wouldn't suggest it in this situation.